# Why ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error on Jtable having one element

Tags: java, jtable

I want to add jTable elements to a list. It works fine when jTable have more then one element, but it gives me the the following error when jTable have one element. Why so? How to resolve it. Thank You.

Here is the error.

> Error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 >= 1

Here is the code:

```
 DefaultTableModel table_tags = (DefaultTableModel)this.jTable_selectedTags.getModel(); 

 int rowCount=table_tags.getRowCount();

 Vector data = table_tags.getDataVector();
 Vector row = (Vector) data.elementAt(1);

 int mColIndex = 0;
 List tags_data = new ArrayList(rowCount);

 for (int i = 0; i < table_tags.getRowCount(); i++) {
        row = (Vector) data.elementAt(i);
        tags_data.add(row.get(mColIndex));
 }
 System.out.println(tags_data);
```

Comment: The one element is at index `0`, not `1`.

Comment: Vector row = (Vector) data.elementAt(1); Are you talking about this.

Comment: Thank you Arnab Hore. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The issues was in accessing of index. So, after changing

```
Vector row = (Vector) data.elementAt(1);
```

to

```
Vector row = (Vector) data.elementAt(0);
```

It worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

Your for loop is wrong. You iterate the table using this condition:

`for (int i = 0; i < table_tags.getRowCount(); i++)`

Problem is that you use the row count to perform the iteration. Given only one element in the Vector your row count would indeed by 1 but using this to iterate over the table would cause it to fail, since the only element at the table would at index 0. Change your above condition to:

`for (int i = 0; i < table_tags.getRowCount() - 1; i++)`

And I suppose you'll be fine.

Comment: Thank you, actually issues was with access of Vector. So, after changing index from 1 to 0. It worked fine. Regards.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm describing above. Considering that you'll need to be iterating over your data, a loop with correct indices is needed.